# HTTPie/cURL don't display cyrillic characters on Windows

Tags: http, unicode, encoding, elasticsearch, cyrillic

I hope one day I won't feel so much despair when facing an encoding problem.

I'm trying to call ElasticSearch HTTP API. PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest` has no problems with cyrillic chars:

```
{
  "_index": "gofra",
  "_type": "orgs",
  "_id": "7104018679",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "inn": "7104018679",
    "name": "МОУДОД \"ДШИ № 4\" Г. ТУЛЫ",
    "nameSuggest": {
      "input": [
        "ДШИ № 4",
        "МОУДОД ДШИ № 4",
        "МОУДОД ДШИ № 4 Г. ТУЛЫ"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But both `cURL`

```
{
  "_index": "gofra",
  "_type": "orgs",
  "_id": "7104018679",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "inn": "7104018679",
    "name": "╨£╨₧╨ú╨ö╨₧╨ö \"╨ö╨¿╨ÿ Γäû 4\" ╨ô. ╨ó╨ú╨¢╨½",
    "nameSuggest": {
      "input": [
        "╨ö╨¿╨ÿ Γäû 4",
        "╨£╨₧╨ú╨ö╨₧╨ö ╨ö╨¿╨ÿ Γäû 4",
        "╨£╨₧╨ú╨ö╨₧╨ö ╨ö╨¿╨ÿ Γäû 4 ╨ô. ╨ó╨ú╨¢╨½"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and [`HTTPie`](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie)

```
{
  "innSuggest": {
    "input": [
      "7104018679"
    ],
    "payload": {
      "inn": "7104018679",
      "name": "?????? \"??? ? 4\" ?. ????"
    }
  },
  "name": "?????? \"??? ? 4\" ?. ????",
  "nameSuggest": {
    "input": [
      "??? ? 4",
      "?????? ??? ? 4",
      "?????? ??? ? 4 ?. ????"
    ]
  }
}
```

..fails, in different ways. What am I doing wrong? I'm particularly interested in using `HTTPie`.

Comment: Where are you displaying the results? Default Windows console doesn't like Unicode.

Comment: I tried both default console and [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I had my system locale set to English. I set it to Russian and the party started immediately.

[image]